# Find nullity of a linear map given some information on the composition of this map with itself 4 times.

Tags: linear-algebra

T is a linear map, T: $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $T^{4}$ := $T \circ T \circ T \circ T$ ($\textbf{x}$)=$\textbf{0}$ for all $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that nullity of T is larger than or equal to $\frac{n}{4}$.
So far I noticed that dimension of the kernel of $T^4$ (and hence its nullity) must be $n$, because all elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ map to $\textbf{0}$. However from there I am not sure how to bound nullity of T. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space and let $S \colon V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map satisfying $S^2 = 0$. Show that $\mathrm{im}(S) \subseteq \ker(S)$ and using the rank-nullity theorem, conclude that $\dim \ker(S) \geq \frac{n}{2}$. Letting $S = T^2$ and $V = \mathbb{R}^n$, conclude that $\dim \ker(T^2) \geq \frac{n}{2}$. Finally, let $V = \ker(T^2)$ and $S = T|_{\ker(T^2)}$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I have shown that Im(S) $\subseteqq$ of Ker(S), but I am not sure how to use rank-nullity after that.

Comment: Rank nullity tells you that $\dim \ker(S) + \dim \mathrm{im}(S) = \dim V = n$ but $\dim \mathrm{im}(S) \leq \dim \ker(S)$. What does it tell you about $\dim \ker (S)$?

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense!